# Expires in 1 month header on all files except .php files

Tags: php, apache, http, caching, expires-header

To speed up my website I have read about the `Expires` header, how to implement it in Apache, and how to only do so for certain file types. However I want to set a one month expiry on **all files except** `.php` files (webpages).

So how do I do this with `.htaccess`? I have a PHP script that uses `filemtime` to change the filename of CSS, JS files when they are edited, so that they are re-downloaded (eg if a file changes at `xxxxxxx` in Unix time, it changes the filename to `/resource.css?recache=xxxxxxxx`  when it is requested). So that's taken care of. As images etc. don't change often, I want all of them to be cached for a month.

Also, what is the browser support for the `Expires` header?

Comment: I don't think you'd need to worry about expiring PHP files or not, seeing as (unless you have an Apache PHP caching plugin) the PHPs will always be rendered dynamically.

Comment: OK, so do I just set `Expires` on all files? How would be best?

Comment: I'm not a caching expert, but people usually use the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers when they *don't* want caching, as all modern browsers are default to cache resources. But yes, the `mod_expires` in Alon's answer should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) in your Apache configuration files. For example:

```
# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 1 month
<filesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A2592000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
```

You can read more [here](http://www.askapache.com/hacking/speed-site-caching-cache-control.html)

Comment: You can also set `ExpiresDefault` with a more readable string. `ExpiresDefault "access plus 365 days"`